# Google APIs Explorer "Timeout while fetching" in Development Server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm creating a project in **Google App Engine** using **Google Cloud Endpoints**. In order to test the endpoints I'm using the **Google APIs Explorer** running in local.

```
localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer
```

With most of my API methods I have no problem, but I have one concrete method that has to call some external services and so on before returning, so I'm always getting an error response in the API Explorer:

```
404 Not Found
{
 "error": {
  "message": "Timeout while fetching: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/spi/MyEndpoint.method"
 }
}
```

I think the APIs Explorer must have some kind of default time limit and I was wondering if there's any way to set this...

**EDIT**: The endpoint works perfectly fine, I mean, it does all the operations as it is supposed to do, it persists all the objects I want, etc. And if I add breakpoints I can see that the program passes by all the steps I want. The problem is that Google APIs Explorer "doesn't want to wait" for the response of the endpoint, even if that response would be perfectly prepared.

Comment: What do your application logs say?

Comment: I see. I believe this is a bug and may have been addressed. Have you upgraded your SDK to 1.7.6?

Comment: No, I'm still working with 1.7.5, I'll update and check again...

Comment: @bossylobster I've updated the SDK to 1.7.6 and I'm still getting the same timeout error...